# How to change thumbnail image ratio iOS Push Notification?

Tags: ios, image, push-notification, push, thumbnails

Is it possible to change the image aspect ratio and its size in the thumbnail of an iOS push notification, how ?

[That is the current Push Notification I get...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2Vyg.png)

[...and that is the render I wish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMrkO.jpg) (image from the Apple WWDC, I suppose it is possible to get the same render ?!)

Comment: did you find the solution to this problem of resizing a rectangular image to show the whole image in notification?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using `UNNotificationAttachment` to show the image on the lock screen, correct? If not, you probably should be for this particular case. In it, you can use `UNNotificationAttachmentOptionsThumbnailClippingRectKey`, where you can specify your cropping rectangle.

If you're trying to get a non-standard aspect ratio, you can specify something like, `CGRectMake(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 0.7)`. This will crop your image at 70% of its original height and cut off the bottom 30%. You can also play around with `x` and `y` values that will move the cropping rectangle from its top-left origin point.

You can, of course, read more about it in [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationattachmentoptionsthumbnailclippingrectkey).

Comment: Indeed I already tried to crop my thumbnail. This allows me to crop the image or to select a part of my source image to display it. In my case I want to resize the render of the displayed image.